# Is there a way to hide the vertical ruler in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a way to hide the vertical ruler in Ace?

By vertical ruler I mean the vertical line in the editor at 80 chars which helps to keep lines under a certain length.

I'd like to give my users the options to enable/disable it If possible

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Found it, you need to use this:

```
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
```

https://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.setShowPrintMargin