# Where to place cloud 9 ace editor configurations?

Tags: cloud9-ide, ace-editor, cloud9

New user of cloud 9. I want to hide the vertical ruler in the editor, found the following SE [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907184/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-vertical-ruler-in-ace-editor), but having a hard time figuring out where to place that code. Where do I place the editor configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ide click on the preferences button, and change the `show print margin` setting in the user settings block.

Alternatively you can use `cloud9>open your user settings` menu item to edit settings as json and change showPrintMargin setting